# Add delay to startup Watchdog on boot Raspberry

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, watchdog

I set up the watchdog to reboot my Raspberry if : fails ping, overheating and if a file is not updated for more than 3 minutes. Now I have a problem: the watchdog start on boot of my Raspberry, but I need to add a delay on watchdog or I could have a bootloop. How can I fix it?

Comment: Same question here... I need to postpone the start of the watchdog by a couple of minutes after boot...

Did you find a solution?